# Connect to ClickHouse Managed ClickHouse in Yandex.Cloud with JetBrains DataGrip, PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, datagrip, clickhouse

How could I connect to ClickHouse in Managed instance on Yandex.Cloud with JetBrains DataGrip or PyCharm using HTTP API and `clickhouse-driver` JDBC?

There are no direct instructions on ClickHouse site or JetBrains site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. hit the + and select clickhouse

image1
[image: select clickhouse]

2. SSH setup - its most likely at your click house server set up on a remote linux server. So you need to setup this up in order to connect to clickHouse

image2
[image: ssh setup]

3. Add you clickhouse address, port number and password

image3
[image: add clickHouse address, port and password]

Answer (score 2):

1. Open database tool window (Alt/Cmd+1)
2. Press +
3. Choose ClickHouse
4. Enter host, credentials and all the other needed details.

[image]

Comment: Relevant for local ClickHouse. I have an issue with connecting to Managed Instance while followed the official docs https://cloud.yandex.com/docs/managed-clickhouse/operations/connect. When I enter `jdbc:clickhouse://<my_instance_id>.mdb.yandexcloud.net:8443/<database_name>` 1002 Exception "failed to respond" raised.

Comment: Looks like not a DataGrip's problem

Comment: documentation states that: `If there is no public access to the DB cluster, you can only connect to it from the Yandex.Cloud virtual machines running in the same cloud network.`